# Will session id be re-generated automatically from time to time?

Tags: php, apache, session, session-state, sessionid

When calling `session_start()` for the first time, a new session will be generated. Later, when `session_start` is called again, the session will be resumed using the session id in the cookie (or from GET/POST request if `session.use_trans_sid` is turned on on the server) sent by the client.

For enhanced security, a new session id can be re-generated for the user from time to time, even when he/she has not logout/login again.

Does this behavior happen automatically, meaning that this is the default setting on most web servers? Or it requires manual coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not happen automatically.

You have to use [`session_regenerate_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php).

> session_regenerate_id() will replace the current session id with a new
>   one, and keep the current session information.

It is a good practice that you change the session id at least every time the user's privilege level changes (simplest example being when he logs in).